# OpenCL compression of binary data

Tags: java, opencl

I'd like to ask for your help if you're experience in OpenCL.
The task is so trivial, it's a shame I can't see what's wrong, but I couldn't solve this for 2 days now.
We have a binary 3D volume data stored in 2D slices. On the CPU side in Java, each slice is compressed into a bit array, that is, each slice's size is calculated as:

```
sliceSize = (width*height+31)/32;
```

The Java code for compressing slices from 1 byte/voxel to 1 int/32 voxels is:

```
    hostUncompressed = new byte[depth * height * width];
    hostCompressed = new int[depth * sliceSize];

    deviceUncompressed = new byte[depth * height * width];
    deviceCompressed = new int[depth * sliceSize];

    int numOnes = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                hostUncompressed[k++] = (byte) (((int) (Math.random() * 1000)) % 2);
                numOnes += (hostUncompressed[k - 1] == 1) ? 1 : 0;
            }
        }
    }
for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i) {
        int start = i * sliceSize;
        int index = start;
        int targetIndex = 0;
        int mask = 1;
        int buffer = 0;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                if (hostUncompressed[index] > 0) {
                    buffer |= mask;
                }
                ++index;
                if ((index & 31) == 0) {
                    hostCompressed[start + targetIndex++] = buffer;
                    buffer = 0;
                    mask = 1;
                } else {
                    mask <<= 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My OpenCL port of it looks like this:

```
public void compress(cl_mem vol, int[] size3, int[] voxels) {
    int totalCompressedSize = voxels.length;

    cl_mem devCompressed = CL.clCreateBuffer(cl.getContext(),
            CL.CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, Sizeof.cl_int * totalCompressedSize,
            null, null);

    int[] sliceSizeInts = new int[]{(size3[0] * size3[1] + 31) / 32};
    int[] dimensions = new int[]{size3[0], size3[1], size3[2], 0};
    long[] localWorkSize = new long[]{1, 1, 1};
    long[] globalWorkSize = new long[]{sliceSizeInts[0], size3[2], 1};

    cl.calcLocalWorkSize(globalWorkSize, localWorkSize);
    CLUtils.round_size(localWorkSize, globalWorkSize);

    int k = 0;
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernels[1], k++, Sizeof.cl_mem,
            Pointer.to(devCompressed));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernels[1], k++, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(vol));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernels[1], k++, Sizeof.cl_int4,
            Pointer.to(dimensions));

    CL.clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(cl.getCommandQueue(), kernels[1], 2, null,
            globalWorkSize, localWorkSize, 0, null, null);

    CL.clEnqueueReadBuffer(cl.getCommandQueue(), devCompressed, CL.CL_TRUE,
            0, Sizeof.cl_int * totalCompressedSize, Pointer.to(voxels), 0,
            null, null);
    CL.clReleaseMemObject(devCompressed);
    CL.clFinish(cl.getCommandQueue());
}

kernel void roiVolume_dataCompress(
global int*     compressed,
global char*    raw,
int4            dimensions) {
int comprSubId = get_global_id(0);
int sliceIndex = get_global_id(1);

int rawSliceSize   = dimensions.y * dimensions.x;
int comprSliceSize = (rawSliceSize + 31)/32;

if ( sliceIndex < 0 || sliceIndex >= dimensions.z ||
     comprSubId < 0 || comprSubId >= comprSliceSize )
    return;

int rawIndex;
int rawSubIndex;
int value = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i)
{   
    rawSubIndex = comprSubId*32+i;
    if ( rawSubIndex < rawSliceSize) 
    {
        rawIndex = sliceIndex * rawSliceSize + rawSubIndex;
        if (raw[rawIndex] != 0)
            value |= (1 << i);
    }
}

int comprIndex = sliceIndex * comprSliceSize + comprSubId;
compressed[comprIndex] = value;
}
```

It works if depth=1, so if executed only on one slice, but from the second slice it gets wrong and I can't see any pattern in the array that could help.

Any help would really be appreciated.
Thank you.